# error: line 9: * 12: syntax error: operand expected

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I've been getting the error: `line 9: * 12: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 12")` (I entered 3, 4, 1 as a test on the script) the result that I need still shows at the end but after this error line. Why is that line showing if everything "works"?

Here's my code so you can understand what I did:

```
y='1'
z='0'

while [ $z = 0 ]
do
read x
        if [[ "$x" -ge "0" ]];
        then
        y=$[$x*$y]
        fi
done

echo -n "The multiplication of positive numbers entered is: $y"

exit
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> line 9: * 12: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 12")
> ```

How is this possible?
The message is trying to tell you that an operand is expected,
but it wasn't there.
As an additional hint, the error token is `* 12`.
Look closely where this might be.

This happens in the expression `$x*$y`.
For example if `x` is 2, and `y` is 12,
then the expression is `2 * 12`.
But if the value of `x` is the empty string,
then the expression is `* 12`, that is,
*nothing* multiplied by 12.
That makes no sense, hence the error.

When `x` has no value (you entered a blank line),
you probably want to break out of the loop:

```
while [ $z = 0 ]; do
    read x
    [[ $x ]] || break
    if [[ "$x" -ge "0" ]]; then
        y=$[$x*$y]
    fi
done
```

In addition,
as [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) pointed out in a comment,
the `$[...]` syntax is obsoleted in favor of `$((...))`,
and there's no good reason to mix `[...]` and `[[...]]` style conditionals.
Here's a more modern, cleaner version of your script,
also with the unused `z` variable eliminated:

```
while true; do
    read x
    [[ $x ]] || break
    if ((x >= 0)); then
        ((y = x * y))
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

How do you end the input? If you entered <kbd>Ctrl + d</kbd> or an empty string, x was emtpy, and the shell tried to assign

```
y=$[*12]
```

Hence the error. I don't see why the loop ends in such a case, though, as `$z` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of this line isn't correct:

```
y=$[$x*$y]
```

To assign the result of `$x * $y` to `$y`, use this:

```
y=$(( x * y ))
```

Remember that the shell only supports integer arithmetic.

Comment: I tried that but now ctrl+d doesn't stop the loop and passes on to the echo bit.

Comment: The problem is a missing operand when `x` is empty, not the syntax.

Comment: `$[...]` is an obsolete, undocumented, but still supported precursor to POSIX `$((...))` syntax.